# Audit and or monitor every command sent through an SSH connection?

Tags: centos, ssh, tty, pam, linux-audit

I am writing because I need a way to monitor what my users send via ssh.

I have a jumphost and I tried the following:

https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Security_Guide/sec-Configuring_PAM_for_Auditing.html

both system-auth and password-auth have the corresponding:

```
session     required      pam_tty_audit.so enable=*
```

With no success, so I tried adding some specific system calls to monitor what is being sent, specifically with execve via auditd

```
-a always,exit -F arch=b64 -S execve
-a always,exit -F arch=b32 -S execve
-w /bin/sudo -p x
-w /bin/ssh -p x
-w /bin/scp -p x
-w /bin/vi -p x
-a always,exit -F arch=b64 -S open`
```

I took a look at the openssh code repository in git and noticed this in the commit notes:

```
auth-pam.c  Remove do_pam_set_tty which is dead code.   
auth-pam.h  Remove do_pam_set_tty which is dead code.
```

So I wondered if this was a depreciated functionality.

At any rate, besides "shell hacks" which can be circumvented by users fairly easily...

Is there any method viable by which I can see what is being sent to a remote host? It seems that the majority of threads that I have found on the topic seem to focus on logging who logged into what, when. I want to see what the user sent to the remote tty/pts from my jumphost which is facilitating the ssh connection.

Thanks for any and all suggestions.